# Relationship between $\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}=0$ and $\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}=0$

Tags: electromagnetism

Does $\partial E / \partial t=0$ imply that $\partial B/ \partial t=0$?
Here's why I think so:

Let $\partial E / \partial t=0$.
By Maxwell equation, $\nabla\times B=\mu_0J$, and, as far as I know, the current density $J$ is proportional to electric field $E$.

Therefore,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla\times B)=\nabla \times \frac{\partial B}{\partial t}=\mu_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t}J=0$$
because $\partial E / \partial t=0$.
Is there anything wrong?

Conversely, does $\partial B / \partial t=0$ imply that $\partial E / \partial t=0$?

Comment: You're assuming Ohm's law $\vec{E} = \sigma \vec{J}$ in some region, which is approximately valid in metals for DC current or current that oscillates at low enough frequencies. Then you have only shown that $\nabla \times \vec{B}$ does not depend on time, or that $\partial_t \vec{B}$ is a conservative field in that region. This does not imply that $\vec{B}$ does not depend on time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are forgetting the Maxwell-Faraday equation:
$$\partial_t\mathbf{B}=-c\nabla\times\mathbf{E}.$$
Now from here you should see that $\partial_t\mathbf{B}=0$ cannot require any sort of time dependence or independence for the electric field. All it necessitates is that the electric field is curl-less.

On the other hand, if $\partial_t\mathbf{E}=0$, then you can use the Maxwell-Faraday equation in the result you obtained:
\begin{align}
\nabla\times\partial_t\mathbf{B}&=\frac{4\pi}{c}\partial_t\mathbf{J} \\
\nabla\times\left(-c\nabla\times\mathbf{E}\right)&=\frac{4\pi}{c}\partial_t\mathbf{J}
\end{align}
which also does not say anything about the time dependence of the magnetic field, the second line only specifies conditions on the spatial dependence of the electric field.

Hence, the time-independence of either field does not imply the time-independence of the other component.

Comment: Then, in my question, thinking "when electric field is time independent, current density is time independent" is wrong?

Comment: And there is no relation between time independence of E and time independence of B?

Comment: per Ignatowski's equations (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations) a time varying current is source to both **magnetic** *and* **electric** fields

Comment: @KHJ that is exactly what I said in my last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

There are counter examples:

In the first case, we can imagine the secondary of a transformer with open ends, and a linearly increasing current in the primary. The magnetic field will also increases linearly, which implies a constant emf (and a constant electric field) in the secondary.

In the second case, we can suppose an electric circuit designed to supply a constant current to charge a capacitor. The electric field between the plates of the capacitor will increase with time, while the magnetic field around the wire (and the capacitor) is constant.